# RSS from Sharepoint wrong character

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding

I made a script that get an RSS feed from a Sharepoint server. Then I extract the text with DOMDocument and add line endings with `\n` It works all fine but at the end of the line it prints a wrong character `â`. What could be the problem? Is it a wrong encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem could be solved. I had to `utf8_decode` the strings first.